# rtk query fetch error: request returns 200 but no data on localhost

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Even though the query is correct and the api is not protected, I get a fetch error and no data. The backend runs locally on a different port than the frontend. We are using rtk query for data fetching.

The basic api setup:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'

const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8000',
})

export const api = createApi({
    baseQuery,
    endpoints: () => ({}),
})
```

The endpoints:

```
import { api } from '../services/api/api'

const ingredientsApi = api.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: (build) => ({
        getIngredients: build.query<any, void>({
            query: () => '/ingredients/load',
            transformResponse: (response) => {
                console.log('Response, ', response)
                return response
            },
        }),
        getRecipe: build.query<any, void>({
            query: () => '/recipes/recipe/154007',
            transformResponse: (response) => {
                console.log('Response, ', response)
                return response
            },
        }),
    }),
    overrideExisting: false,
})

export const { useGetIngredientsQuery, useGetRecipeQuery } = ingredientsApi
```

We are wrapping out app with the ApiProvider.

The error we get is {status: 'FETCH_ERROR', error: 'TypeError: Failed to fetch'}.

If we use an open api, we receive data, so the basic setup works.
If we call the api in the browser (http://localhost:8000/ingredients/load), the data shows, so the api works as well.
The data the api sends is in json format, so as expected.

We are out of ideas why our requests fail, any hints are appreciated!